# Java byte message validation with STX, ETX and DLE

Tags: java, algorithm, validation, byte

Hello guys I am trying to figure out how to check for a byte message validation in Java. Supposing that:

```
    STX = 0x02 bytes   //start text data.
    ETX = 0x03 bytes   // end text data.
    DLE = 0x04 bytes   //data link escape.
```

A valid message is one that starts with STX has DLE and ends with and ETX.

How can I check if a message is valid according to the above values???

```
     byte[] message =
      { 0x02, 0x10, 0x02, 0x10, 0x10, 0x07, 0x08, 0x03, 0x14 };
```

I am not asking to get any kind of code I just need to figure out how to approach this specific problem. Any ideas would be much appriciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and fast approach - use [finite-state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) (automaton).
Initial state is "WaitForSTX", then state changes to "WaitForDLE", then to "WaitForETX". If automaton is in "WaitForETX" state and meet ETX byte, it finishes with success.

P.S. Could regular expressions be applied to byte arrays in Java?

Comment: Thanks for your reply I ll have a look and I don't that regular expressions can be applied in byte arrays(not totally sure).